# Passing Parameters ins JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf, glassfish

till now i used in JSF 1.2 commandLinks and the setPropertyActionListener to pass for e.g. the selectedItem of a DataTable.

```
<h:commandLink action="#{Result.show}" value="#{foo.name}">
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{foo}" target="#{Result.selectedFoo}"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

In an example [JSF 2.0 and JPA](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jsf-20-jpa-glassfish-and-mysql) i have seen a solution, where the selected Item is passed as parameter to a function. But if i try to execute this function on a Glassfish 2.1 Server i'am getting an Exception.

```
<h:commandLink action="#{Result.showFoo(foo)}" value="#{foo.name}">
        
            </h:commandLink>
```

javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException:
javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing:
javax.servlet.ServletException:

I'm only using simple ManagedBeans, no EJB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Unified Expression Language (all that `#{}`/`${}` stuff) is maintained as part of the JSP spec. You probably need a newer version of the JSP API. I see that [Glassfish v3](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/downloads/v3-final.html) includes EL 2.2. I believe that spec includes the functionality you want.